# How to get the Order status changed date in Woocoomerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woothemes

I need to get the date in which the order status is changed.

For example 123 is order id , the order is created in 12-12-2015 , and order is confirmed in 13-12-2015 . So I need to know in which date order is confirmed from order id?

Comment: try `$order = new WC_Order($order_id); echo $order->order_date; echo $order->modified_date; `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In woocommerce,

Try

```
$order = new WC_Order($order_id);
echo $order->modified_date;
```

Comment: Hi really thank you for this answer . Then how i check that is this order is modified in 13-12-2015  and the order status is confirmed ?

Answer (score 2):

Never access order properties directly. Use this to get the order modified date:

```
$order = new WC_Order($order_id);
$modified_date = get_the_modified_date( $order );

echo $modified_date;
```

Comment: what if we changed other details for this order? modified_date updates even if we change other things