# Find time between order marked as processing to order marked as completed

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to find the time from order processing to order marked as complete for every order. How can I get that? I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34369846/how-to-get-the-order-status-changed-date-in-woocoomerce) and it only gives time for last modified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get all the orders and return the number of seconds between the order being placed and if it is currently at a completed status.  You haven't specified a format for the time difference so I have just returned it as a string with the corresponding order id.

```
$query = new WC_Order_Query( array(
    'limit' => -1,
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'return' => 'ids',
) );

foreach( $query->get_orders() as $order_id ) {
    $order = wc_get_order($order_id);
    if( $order->get_status() === 'completed') {
        $order_data = $order->get_data();
        $timestamp = $order_data['date_modified']->getTimestamp() - $order_data['date_created']->getTimestamp();
        $d1 = new DateTime();
        $d2 = new DateTime();
        $d2->add(new DateInterval('PT'.$timestamp.'S'));
        $order_interval = $d2->diff($d1);
        echo 'Order ID : ' . $order->get_id() . ' ' . $order_interval->format('%a days, %h hours, %i minutes and %s seconds');
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks @FahadUddin, if you could accept my answer that would be awesome :)

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this?

```
$order_id = 1945;
$order = new WC_Order($order_id);
$order_data = $order->get_data();
$date1 = $order_data['date_created']->date( 'Y-m-d G:i:s' );
$date2 = $order_data['date_modified']->date( 'Y-m-d G:i:s' );
$diff = abs(strtotime($date2) - strtotime($date1));
$years = floor($diff / (365*60*60*24));
$months = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24) / (30*60*60*24));
$days = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24 - $months*30*60*60*24)/ (60*60*24));
printf("%d years, %d months, %d days\n", $years, $months, $days);
```

You can improved this by adding a check for the status of the order.